# Reset all columns of a row type to NULL

Tags: postgresql, null, initialization, plpgsql, bulk

I was wondering if it's possible to bulk initialize variables that are created from a type to null without initializing them each separately

```
create type tp_data as (
    data01   text,
    data02   integer,
    data03   text
);

create function sp_function()
  returns setof tp_data as
$$
declare
    lr_data   tp_data;
begin
    for lr_data in
        select data.data01, data.data02, data.data03
        from data
    loop
        if lr_data.data01 = "cancelled" then

            -- what is the correct way to do this?
            lr_data.* := null;

            -- without having to do this
            lr_data.data01 := null;
            lr_data.data02 := null;
            lr_data.data03 := null;
        end if;

        return next lr_data;
    end loop;
end
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
select * from sp_function();
```

The above is clearly wrong however in Informix I am able to use something like "initialize lr_data.* to null". Is there a way to do something similar in plpgsql?

Comment: Have you tried to define your type with something like this: `.... data01   text DEFAULT NULL, ....`

Comment: That won't help because the data will be filled with results from the sql query at that point. I need to be able to clear all the results returned for that row after the sql query has run

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just ***assign*** `NULL` to the whole row type:

```
lr_data := null;
```

This sets every single column to `NULL`.

Aside: there are a couple of syntax errors in your function. And the whole function could be radically simplified. This query replaces the whole function:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN data01 = 'cancelled' THEN NULL::tp_data ELSE d::tp_data END).*
FROM (SELECT data01, data02, data03 FROM data) d;
```

Not the point of your question, I know. But it demonstrates that we can also ***cast*** a `NULL` value to the row type to make all columns `NULL`.

Comment: also yeah, this function is written as complete crap just to make my question clear

Comment: the addendum is good to know but the null assignment is needed for a more complex function